# Block uses an outer variable in Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

In some `myClass` class I have:

```
foo
   |i b|
   i := 5.
   b := [i := i * 2. i].
   i :=3.
   ^b
```

I run:

```
|a i b1 b2|
i := 4.
a := MyClass new.
b1 := a foo.
b2 := a foo.
Transcript show: b1 value; cr.
i := 1.
Transcript show: b1 value; cr.
Transcript show: b2 value; cr.
```

I don't understand why the output is:

```
6
12
6
```

Is it possible to explain how the compiler figures it out?

Comment: Figures out what? `i := 5` does not make any difference because you re-assign `i` anyway. `i` and `b` are temp vars. They are scoped to a method invocation. Thus each time you call a method, the `i` there is different (it's not some kind of instance variable or something else with a global scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you get is the expected behavior. First of all the temporary `i` defined in the script, regardless of its name, has no influence or relationship whatsoever with temporary `i` in the `#foo` method, so you can get rid of it from the script.

Secondly, the method answers with a `BlockClosure`, namely `[i := i*2. i]`. Which means that it will remember the value of `i`, double it, and then return it. As a side effect, the method also sets the value of `i` to `3`.

Then, when you evaluate `b` for the first time, `i` starts at `3`, is doubled to `6` and then returned. Hence, you get `6`. The second evaluation just evaluates the block, so it uses the current value of `i`, which is `6`, doubles it and answers with the result, which is `12`. Evaluate `b` again and you will get `24`, `48`, etc.

Also note that every time you send `#foo`, the block it answers will evaluate to `6`.

### Appendix

The question mentions the compiler. Well, the compiler does very little in the script. In `#foo`, however, it does something more sophisticated, it creates the `BlockClosure` with code `[i := i * 2. i]`. Temporaries not used in blocks live in the stack, but this temporary `i` does not. Why? Because the block is an object that will survive the execution of the method, and the stack is gone as soon as the method returns. The block will then allocate the variable `i` in an `Array` that represents the environment the block needs to keep working. This `Array` is not allocated in the stack but in the object memory. This is where the block remembers the last value of `i`, and can update and use it as many times as needed even after the invokation of `#foo`, along with the stack it used gets ovewritten by other invocations. (And yes, in Smalltalk the compiler is a first class object too.)

Comment: I didn't even pay attention on the `i`s in the script :)

Comment: @Uko I think that the code should be written differently - the `i` would deserve a next line to stress it.  I love the Leandro explains the stuff, there is usually nothing to add or take away.